# how to sort a table based on a specific column (both scending and descending) in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need your help to sort a table based on a specific column in ascending and descending order.

For example I have this table saved in a file called "test.txt"

which contains the following:

- Name,BirthYear,Job
- Ahmed,1990,Engineer
- Salim,1997,Teacher
- Nasser,1993,Accountant

I converted it to a csv table with prettytable:

```
from prettytable import from_csv
import csv, operator

with open('test.txt', 'r') as open_file:
    table_file = from_csv(open_file)
print(table_file)
```

[the picture is attached as 1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QfY3.png)

Then I sorted it based on BirthYear column:

```
print(table_file.get_string(sortby='BirthYear', sort_key=lambda row: row[0]))
```

[the picture is attached as 2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQIh1.png)

How to sort the same but in descending order? (based on any column, not only BirthYear column).

If you have different ways, it would be greate to know learn them.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What would happen if instead of `lambda row: row[0]` you will have `lambda row: -row[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use sorted() if you want to sort data in descending order, just add reverse=True in sorted function but it allows you to sort only one column at a time.

```
from prettytable import from_csv
import csv, operator

with open('test.txt', 'r') as open_file:
  table_file = from_csv(open_file)
print(table_file)
 
srt =  sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True) 
print(st)
```

or you can use pandas

```
from prettytable import from_csv
import csv, operator
import pandas as pd


with open('test.txt', 'r') as open_file:
    table_file = from_csv(open_file)
print(table_file)
srt = table_file.sort_values(["Age"], axis=0, ascending=[False], inplace=True)
print(st)
```

I hope that gonna helps you .